# Ember Data ID is sent where as ASP.NET WebApi expect object

Tags: asp.net, ember-data, asp.net-web-api2

I have a project specific requirement where the Frontend is being developed using EmberJS with EmberData.

Now as you might be aware that Ember defines relationship through IDs and on submit it sends that model with ID reference singular/ or array back to the server.

Where as at server end I am expecting an object.

for e.g

Student.cs

class Student {
   Profile profile {get;set;}
}

Profile.cs

class Profile { 
 ....
}

On saving Student, instead of sending profile object it is sending profile id, which from server side how can I modify so that if it sends an ID then it converts back to an object automatically?

Here is the snippet of the JSON that is sent by Ember.

```
{
  "request": {
    "dateCreated": null,
    "dateModified": null,
    "dateDue": null,
    "department": null,
    "businessUnit": null,
    "status": null,
    "description": "asdfasda",
    **"author": "1",**
    "project": null,
    "attachments": []
  }
}
```

Now you can see that the author is defined as ID, now how can I solve this problem at server side that these IDs are mapped back to the an object.